# Undefined function error after moving theme to web server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using wordpress and I have created a child theme off of the Twenty Sixteen theme. I've tested this on php v7.1.8 and everything (appears) to work fine. I moved the theme and plugins over to my web server which is running 7.3.9 and I get this error to appear:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentysixteen_the_custom_logo() in /wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/header.php:33

My assumption is it would pull that from the twentysixteen theme but appears that it is not? Any ideas on how to fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what happened originally but I think something didn't install properly. I re-installed WP and moved the child over and it worked fine this time.